# Jmeter JDBC Call stored procedure with BLOB Parameter

Tags: jmeter, blob

I should call a stored procedure with BLOB parameter.

Parameter type is BloB, how can I send a file as a BLOB datatype in parameter value?

Comment: @Dmitri I really need your help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know, the instructions will differ depending on the [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) system you're using.

For example for [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) database you can call [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function.

Example setup:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

If you want to replicate the described behaviour:

1. [Create table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) statement:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE test_blob( ID INT, IMAGE BLOB);
   ```
2. [Create stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) statement:

   ```
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE testBlobSp (IN ID INT, IN IMAGE BLOB)
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO test_blob values (ID, IMAGE);
   END
   //
   ```

More information: [Performance Testing BLOB from a MySQL Database with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-blob-from-a-mysql-database-with-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks, It's DB2, the parameter is defined like `IN PI_FILE      BLOB(20M)`, I add two libraries 1- db2jcc-license-cisuz-9.1.0 and 2- db2jcc-9.1.0 ... Note that I tried `LOAD_FILE` and `FROM_FILE` but did not worked. Also I used a beanshell processor and convert file to byte array and sent it as `BLOB`, this did not work either